# how to prevent popup window on right mouse click

Tags: jquery

So as the title says how could i do it?

After some googling i got this code together:

```
$('.lines').mousedown(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 1){
        console.log("left");
    }else{
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("right");
    }
});
```

So first i need to determine which button was pushed because i'm going to use different action. but `event.preventDefault` for some reason doesn't do it's job when right mouse button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try that:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Actually, it's annoying, when you can't use right mouse on a website.

---

You can disable it for any particular block in the same way:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $('#test').bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    }); 
});​
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="test"> ​No right clicks allowed here! </div>​
```

And sample CSS:

```
#test { width: 200px; height: 200px; background: red; }
```

And, finally, [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/x4axm/)

Comment: I didn't know that i can bind more then one action to the element and they could work together, thank you, now i have binded `mousedown` and `contextmenu` and it works perfectly